# Retrieving values of the fields which have specified type

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection, refactoring

I have the following code which is a private method inside the form and retrieve all context menus from the form. I feel, that it is not that concise as it should be. Would be grateful for any suggestions.

```
  private IEnumerable<ContextMenuStrip> GetContextMenus()
    {
        var type = this.GetType();
        var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var contextMenus = fields.Where(f => f.GetValue(this).GetType() == typeof(ContextMenuStrip));
        var menus = contextMenus.Select(f=> f.GetValue(this));
        return menus.Cast<ContextMenuStrip>();        
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you happy to include subclasses of ContextMenuStrip? If so, I'd use:

```
return GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Select(field => field.GetValue(this))
                .OfType<ContextMenuStrip>();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = (from f in GetType().GetFields(
                 BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            select f.GetValue(this)).OfType<ContextMenuStrip>();
```

Comment: Thank you. I have two answers with two different styles of querying. Both are great. I don't know which one I should accept.:)

Answer (score 0):

If that code is in a form, you might want to avoid reflection altogether, and just loop over the Controls collection, something like:

```
var controls = from Control c in Controls.AsQueryable()
               where c is ContextMenuStrip
               select c;
```

or the un-LINQed variant

```
IEnumerable<ContextMenuStrip> result = new List<ContextMenuStrip>();
foreach (var control in Controls)
{
   ContextMenuStrip menuStrip = (control as ContextMenuStrip)
   if (menuStrip != null )
   {
     result.Add(menuStrip);
   }
}
return result;
```

Comment: Looking at the fields is different to looking at the Controls collection. Not all controls are fields, and not all fields are (directly) in the Controls collection (even if they are Controls). So a valid answer, but it does something different.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but reflection can usually be an overkill. I admit that the OP was explicit about fields, but I'll leave this answer here if anybody stumbles upon it first. BTW, an int field will not be in the controls collection, but how can a control not be a field?